# Assigning HTML contents to PHP variables

Tags: php

Hard to explain, how to assign HTML contents to PHP variables. The HTML contents are not within the PHP script.as

```
<?php $a_div = ?><div>Contents goes <b>here</b></div>
```

Comment: Email contents are in HTML, what i want is to mail this content using the mail() fucntion

Comment: you need to post a full example of your HTML

Comment: and your PHP code, so, we'll be able to show you how to use PHP tags

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with ob_get_contents: [`ob_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) or [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>Contents goes <b>here</b></div>
<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Comment: Should probably use [`ob_get_clean`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) instead.

Comment: @charles Thanks, ob_get_clean added.

Comment: for the mail sending script it doesn't really matter.

Comment: `ob_get_contents` just get contents, `ob_get_clean` is a connection of `ob_get_contents()` and [`ob_end_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

Comment: @Xcoder because you have difficulties explaining your question.

Comment: What is the hell with these solutions. I dont want to display the output. Just to mail using the mail function.

Comment: __So you could write it in your question!__

Comment: Hii @Robik.. can i use the same code to write PHP code in place of HTML.. will it work ??

Comment: Love this. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 20):

If its **raw HTML**, with no PHP in it, stored in separate file it would be just

```
$a_div = file_get_contents('email.html');
```

If it's PHP file with HTML mixed with PHP then include it using output buffering like in Robik's answer.

```
ob_start();
include 'mail.template.php';
$a_div = ob_get_contents();
```

But if it's relatively small, I'd use HEREDOC

```
$a_div = <<<HERE
<div>Contents goes <b>here</b></div>
HERE;
```

Comment: This makes sense, but where the PHP tag starting and ending?

Comment: <?php
$a_div = <<<HERE ?>
<div>Contents goes <b>here</b></div>
<?php HERE; ?>

Comment: @Xcoder just like elsewhere in your scripts. Right before any PHP code. Ending tag is not necessary though

Comment: my output:
<pre>
$a_div = <<
Contents goes here
HERE; 
</pre>

Comment: @Xcoder make it in separate file, dude, and just load it's contents.

Answer (score 6):

If needed (normally I'm using html templates, replacing placeholders by php) ... 
there are two ways:

```
$testVar = <<<EndOfHtml
<div style="border: 48px solid red">test</div>
EndOfHtml;

print $testVar
```

the easier way, not too elegant - wrap html code in single quotes. so you don't have to escape any double quote:

```
$test_var = '<div style="border: 48px solid red">test</div>'
```

helpful? :-)

Comment: I m confused that where to start and end PHP

Comment: @Sarah make sure that when you write your `EndOfHtml;` closing heredoc that there is no whitespace before it on that line.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for token-terminated Block-Strings?
http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html

Best I can do. Unfortunately your question is a little vague.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, and it's not exactly what was asked, but if you're looking to render the page out of order (such as with templating), one could also wrap that section with a function and call it to render it in the desired location.

```
<?php function RenderFooter() { ?>
    <footer>some footer</footer>
<?php } ?>

<h1>Some header</h1>
<main>Some content</main>

<?= RenderFooter(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) To parse html file and get contents you need.

Comment: What is the hell with these solutions. I dont want to display the output. Just to mail using the mail function.